# Data type for searching by several individual fields in a set of rows?

Tags: java, search, types

Suppose we have a set of rows with selected fields in memory.

How to organize fast search for all rows by specific field equal to some value or in some range (each time we select individual row)?

What is data type used to organize such search?

For equality condition search I see a way by maintaining hash-tables per field, for range search - tree or heap structure. So it build by aggregating existent well defined data structures.

Is it right way or there are another data type that handle point or range selects from row sets by some individual row (but able for first and then second)?

I use Java runtime. Is there something special in standard class library?

My code example:

```
class Empl {
    public String phone;
    public String ldap;
    public String name;
}

class EmplSearchService {
    Map<String, Empl> lookupByPhone = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Empl> lookupByLdap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void add(Empl e) {
         lookupByPhone.put(e.phone, e);
         lookupByLdap.put(e.ldap, e);
    }

    public Empl findByEmail(String email) {
         return lookupByPhone.get(email);
    }
    public Empl findByLdap(String ldap) {
         return lookupByLdap.get(ldap);
    }
}
```

Comment: You refer to rows and fields but I'm assuming you mean objects? In other words you are asking how to quickly search for objects in a collection that satisfy some condition? Though you mention selecting rows so perhaps you're referring to JTable? Basically you need to rephrase this question to make it clearer what you are asking for.

Comment: `JTable` is `awt` storage object and doesn't support required operations. By rows and fields I mean regular Java objects, but question isn't restricted Java platforms in general.

Answer (score 1):

A standard technique from DB technology is inversion which is suitable for fields with a discrete value type V, occurring repeatedly. You create

```
Map<V,BitSet> value2indices
```

where the bit set indicates indices of records containing some value from V.

This will not only give you the index values of all rows where some value occurs. You can also compute the union of BitSets for a range (or an arbitrary set) of values. You can compute the intersection of BitSets for queries combining two or more conditions.

Memory requirements are, of course, to be considered.